# How to create user in postgres using ansible having only read only (SELECT) access

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am creating postgres user using below code. and it is working fine.

```
- name: create database user
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user: db={{ db_name }} name=username password=userpassword priv=CONNECT encrypted=yes state=present
```

However i would like this user to give only readonly access.
I want to grant only select operation on tables in public schema. I can do this using below queries

```
CREATE USER rouser WITH PASSWORD 'pass';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO rouser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO rouser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO rouser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO rouser;
```

I am able to create such user using

```
- name: modify user role 
  become_user: postgres 
  postgresql_privs: 
   db: mydb 
   role: qarouser 
   objs: ALL_IN_SCHEMA 
   privs: SELECT
```

However when i create a new table using different user in the same db. this user do not have select access to such table created by different user, How can i fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290837/ansible-create-postgresql-user-with-access-to-all-tables

Comment: Since you are already using the module `postgresql_user` module you may also have a look into [Community.Postgresql](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/index.html).

Comment: @kildisismail I am able to give select access using - name: modify user role
      become_user: postgres
      postgresql_privs:
        db: mydb
        role: qarouser
        objs: ALL_IN_SCHEMA
        privs: SELECT   but when i add new table, this user do not get permission to select from new table

Comment: correction to above comment "when new table is added by different user"

Answer (score 0):

You already have the modify user role task which gives access to current objects but you are missing ALTER DEFAULT PRIVS... part of your statements. [You can get more samples and much better explanation here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_privs_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-privs-module) Specifically the sample for adding SELECT and USAGE (modified for your use):

```
# Available since version 2.7
# Objs must be set, ALL_DEFAULT to TABLES/SEQUENCES/TYPES/FUNCTIONS
# ALL_DEFAULT works only with privs=ALL
# For specific
- name: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO qarouser, step 1
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    db: mydb
    objs: TABLES
    privs: SELECT
    type: default_privs
    role: qarouser

- name: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO qarouser, step 2
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    db: mydb
    objs: TYPES
    privs: USAGE
    type: default_privs
    role: qarouser
```

I just had to deal with it in my own playbook and found your question while looking for it. Full disclosure: I'm not a DBA nor do I play one on TV. I have not stayed in any fancy hotel that somehow makes me qualified.